# how to refresh a pdf loaded using vscode-pdf?

Tags: vscode-pdf

I have installed the vsccode-pdf plugin:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tomoki1207.pdf

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it to refresh an already loaded file. Not only does it not auto-refresh, there doesn't seem to be an option to refresh it manually. The only way for me to refresh is to close it and re-open - not very practical.

Comment: the 'latex workshop' extension provides a pdf viewer that used to work for me (now it doesn't for some unknown reason but I assume that's something specific to my machine) - you might want to try that out.

I still haven't found an easy answer to this and it's quite frankly frustrating that there isn't a manual refresh button